# Maven не видит класс из другого модуля

Tags: java, maven

При сборке проекта Maven выдает следующие ошибки:

> Error:(25,42) java: package com.notification.dto does not exist
>   Error:(26,46) java: package com.notification.service does not exist
>   Error:(99,5) java: cannot find symbol

При этом зависимость подключена:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>example-notification</artifactId>
  <version>${project.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

IDEA ошибок не выдает, ибо все импорты есть:

```
import com.notification.dto.NotificationRequestDTO;
import com.notification.service.NotificationService;
```

В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: `${project.version}` может использовать версию модуля, а не всего проекта? и что указано в `dependencyManagement`?

Comment: на вскидку пара вариантов: 1. в репозитарии неактуальная версия, 2. если версия x.x.x-SNAPSHOT, то при сборке мавен не обновляет артефакт из удаленного репозитария, если "такой" есть в локальной